# Android App Development, Dynamic Buttons & Fields

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Let me preface my question by saying I have done a lot of research in creating dynamic buttons within an android app, and most are simply wrong or have a different view of dynamic than I do.  If I missed something then just post the link and I'll check it out.

What I'm looking for is a way to create a button within my app based on information I gather from internet sources.  For instance, when someone creates a post on a forums that I care to see, the app will find this, parse it for me, and return some info.  Since I can't fit all this info on screen for each post that shows up, I want to create a button dynamically that previews this info.  Such as name of user, date, and short description (as a preview that by clicking, will give all of the inforamtion in a separate activity).  For the sake of this post, lets pretend I get this info from a text-entry location (not from an actual internt forum post).

First and foremost, how do I create the button dynamically?  The other half of my question is less important to me.  I would like to do this programmatically.  Links to tutorials are great.

Secondly, and less important... Once I have created this button dynamically, how can I get custom views of the button based on a predictable format.

If anything is unclear, just ask and I'll try to clarify. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Could you clarify a bit about what you mean with 'create it dynamically' and why you want to do everything programmatically? Basically, what would be wrong with creating the basic layout in XML and then just fill the fields with the data you fetch from internet?

Comment: The idea is the app works on its own to grab info from the web.  Like if I were to distribute the app, and there was a new post to said forums, the app grabs the info and creates a new button in the app without any new coding being done.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you want a list of buttons? And all the buttons would have the same format/fields, just different content?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the right approach is to have an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) that will map the data to a certain view (a button in your case).

What adapter you choose will be depending on how you decide to fetch and store the data from internet.

When there are new posts you will be adding them to the data source (a database, a list, etc...) and you will call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) which will refresh the list, dynamically creating as many views as needed to display all the data.

Comment: I appreciate this, because this will become a concern soon, although the original question needs to be fixed first.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answers your question. The idea is to programatically create a button, and then add it to the current layout. Somethiug like this:

```
Button newButton = new Button(this);
newButton.setText("Click Me");
newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
}
});
container.addView(newButton);
```

Where container is the layout that will hold the button (i.e. will become it's parent). You can also add layout settings to the button if desired.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for, but not positive because I cannot get it to compile.  So lets say I add this to my activity.  Where you put container would be the id name of the layout I want the button to exist?  Even if I got this to work it doesn't make it dynamic does it?  I thought it would be something like "If button pressed, create new button with x,y,z... parameters" all within the app.   The only static button being the one that creates new buttons.

Comment: Well, then just create the new button in the onClick() method of the button you're pressing.

Comment: how can I create an indeterminate number of buttons in the onClick() method?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create a new `Button`, and set an `onClickListener` as so:

```
    Button button = new Button(context);
    button.setText("New Button");
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    });
```

If you have anything else you need to set, such as an ID, you can call the method as you wish. You will need then add it to your layout as so:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
button.setLayoutParams(params);             
layout.addView(button);
```

There is of course more you can do with it, but that should get you started, and anything else you need you should be able to find by perusing the docs.

If you need help with anything more specifically, then just comment and I will attempt to elaborate.

Comment: After working with your code and trying to understand what was happening better, it looks like your solution is correct.  However my emulator gave me an error message, unable to start app.  Some source of issues could be the line where you create the new button.  You have (context) rather than (this).  What do you mean here?  I got an error with (context) so I changed it to (this).  Next, I added your linearlayout code to the onClick method.  Is this correct?  I'm unsure where the my issue exists because theoretically it makes sense.

Comment: I use `context` instead of this, because in my Class body on every class I create, I have `Context context;` Then in my `onCreate` of every class I have, I put `context = this;`. That way, every time I need to reference a context, I can do so with no issues. For example: If you are within an `onClickListener`, then using `this` for the context doesn't work, so I refer to my global variable `context`. You are free to use `this`. I just prefer to setup the `context` variable as I described. It's simpler.

Comment: I would recommend putting the layout instantiation line in your `onCreate`. Then, you would retrieve data from the internet, and update your layout after using the `params`, `setLayoutParams` and `addView` lines, and this will add a button to the screen. In the `onClick` of said button, you would place whatever code you need to `startActivity`. Another person answered recommending an Adapter. That may work better for you, but I don't know as I have no experience with them. In my apps, the above method was satisfactory.